# Maintaining the balance of a rod of uniform density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment

Assume a rod which:

1. is of uniform density $\rho$.
2. is a metre long.

The rod is balanced on a knife edge at 58 cm. mark (in the notation where the extreme left side is assumed to be 0). To the extreme right edge of the rod there's a 20gf acting downwards. The question is what should the weight of the rod for it to be balanced horizontally on the knife edge?

I have 2 approaches to this problem and both of them yield different answers which I have trouble understanding.

**APPROACH 1**

$\rho = M_1 / 100$,
By the conservation of the moment, we get,
$$58M_1/100 \times 58 = (20 \times 42) + (42 M_1/100 \times 42)$$
where, the origin I have taken is at 58 cm mark.

Solving this equation for $M_1$, we get, $M_1 = 52.5g$.

**APPROACH 2**

Assuming all the weight ($M_2$) of the rod is acting at the centre of Mass of the rod, we get, from the moment conservation equation (again assuming that the 58 cm mark is the origin),
$$M_2 \times (58 -50) = 20 \times 42$$
Hence, $M_2 = 105g$.

Now, I fail to understand why the two approaches which are both correct as per me, yielding different answers, precisely, why is $M_2 = 2 M_1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach 2 yields the correct answer. There’s a slight problem with your approach 1 that is resulting in that factor-of-2 difference.

While treating the rod as a single body with the centre of gravity lying at the 50cm mark is a much simpler approach, there is no problem with separating the rod into two at the knife point. The issue is that you need to be careful of where the centres of gravity of each sub-rod lie. According to your formula in approach 1, the centre of gravity of the 58cm-long sub-rod lies at their far left, while that of the 42cm-long sub-rod lies at the far right.

However, the centres of gravity of each sub-rod should lie at the 29cm and 79cm marks respectively, i.e. at the halfway points. Therefore, your formulation should look like:

$$(58M_1/100)\times 29 = (20\times 42) + (42M_1/100)\times 21$$

Answer (score 1):

Your approach 2 is the correct one because the equation that you have formed in the first case is incorrect. The net force due to the weight of the individual body is usually marked at the Centre of mass of the body. Which in this case will be 8cm to the left of the hinge. This is the simpler approach 2. In your approach one, you have considered the force due to the weight of the left side of the lever at the very left end and the right side of the lever at the very right end and used the torque equation which is incorrect. Actually, it is the Centre of gravity, where it can be assumed, all the weight of the body is acting. Since your body is quiet small (1m) and you haven't mentioned anything about the gravitational field (whether it is constant or not).. We can assume that the Centre of gravity and Centre of mass coincides. Thus, calculating the torque due to the weight of the body, one should should assume the weight to be acting at the Centre of mass and then calculate torque. And if you want to separate the 2 rods and consider them separately, the weight of the individual sub parts should be assumed at the 0.29 m and 0.79 m (from the left end of the rod). Now if you use the torque equation, It will yield the correct answer. Hope this answer helped.